# Run Postgres string function on column created in same query

Tags: postgresql, string-function

Using Postgres 11, how can I execute a series of string functions in the same query, where subsequent string function calls execute against the results of previously executed string functions?

My source table `labels` looks like this:

| descr |
| --- |
| 12345_orange |
| 23456B_yellow |
| 34567C_blue |

I would like to create a view that can return this:

| descr | id | rate | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345_orange | 12345 |  | orange |
| 23456B_yellow | 23456 | B | yellow |
| 34567C_blue | 34567 | C | blue |

A tricky part here is that the column `desc` is not consistent. Sometimes the value `rate` exists and sometimes it does not, as shown in the first row. It seems the easiest way to solve this would be to use a series of two functions where first I extract the value for `id` and store that in a column. Then from that column extract the value for `rate`, if it exists.

Here is the query I am attempting:

```
SELECT
    labels.descr,
    SPLIT_PART(labels.descr, '_', 1) as id
    , REGEXP_MATCHES(id, '[A-Za-z]')
FROM
    labels
;
```

When I execute that I receive the error that column `id` does not exist.

Can someone help me understand how I can solve this problem? I am hoping to solve this using a view only, for simplicity in future queries against this result set.

Additionally I would really appreciate an insight into why the above does not work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use subqueries:

```
SELECT labels_descr,
       id,
       REGEXP_MATCHES(id, '[A-Za-z]')
FROM (SELECT labels.descr,
             SPLIT_PART(labels.descr, '_', 1) as id
      FROM labels) AS subq;
```

or CTEs:

```
WITH subq AS (
   SELECT labels.descr,
          SPLIT_PART(labels.descr, '_', 1) as id
   FROM labels)
SELECT labels_descr,
       id,
       REGEXP_MATCHES(id, '[A-Za-z]')
FROM subq;
```